# How can I convert vim8 function mapping to vim9?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, functions, vim9script, vim9

I have a function in `vim8` as:

```
function! BSkipQuickFix(command)
  let start_buffer = bufnr('%')
  execute a:command
  while &buftype ==# 'quickfix' && bufnr('%') != start_buffer
    execute a:command
  endwhile
endfunction

nnoremap <F12> :call BSkipQuickFix("bn")<CR>
nnoremap <S-F12> :call BSkipQuickFix("bp")<CR>
```

which I have converted to vim9 as:

```
def BSkipQuickFix(command: string): string
  let start_buffer = bufnr('%')
  execute a:command
  while &buftype ==# 'quickfix' && bufnr('%') != start_buffer
    execute a:command
  endwhile
enddef

nnoremap <F12> : BSkipQuickFix("bn")<CR>
nnoremap <S-F12> : BSkipQuickFix("bp")<CR>
```

Now, I am getting `E117: Unknown function: BSkipQuickFix`. Any help please?

Comment: You did not convert it, so the function is not compiled and you can't use it, because it is unknown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would go with `:h vim9-differences` before converting legacy to vim9 script.

In your `def` function:

0. remove last `: string` in `def` as function returns nothing
1. `let` should be replaced with `var`
2. `a:command` should be replaced with `command`
3. `nnoremap` should use `<scriptcmd>BSkipQuickFix("bn")<CR>` without `:`